# unable to create hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am unable to create hive table. 
Following is the code

```
CREATE TABLE NYSE(exchange STRING, stock_symbol STRING, stock_date DATE,
stock_price_open FLOAT, stock_price_high FLOAT, stock_price_low FLOAT,     
stock_price_close FLOAT, stock_volume INT, stock_price_avg_close FLOAT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

This returns me the following error message:

```
NoViableAltException(332@[2189:1: columnNameTypeOrPKOrFK : ( ( foreignKeyWithName ) | ( primaryKeyWithName ) | ( primaryKeyWithoutName ) | ( foreignKeyWithoutName ) | ( columnNameType ) );])
at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFK(HiveParser.java:42212)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeOrPKOrFKList(HiveParser.java:37938)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:5259)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2763)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1756)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1178)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:329)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1158)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1253)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:18 cannot recognize input near 'exchange' 'STRING' ,' in column name or primary key or foreign key
```

I am using Hive 2.1.0 and Hadoop 2.7.3

please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use "exchange" [Reserved keywords](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords) in your column name definition.

try giving like exchange_1 or escape it using ` to your first column name.

Try these steps:

```
USE your_DB_Name;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NYSE PURGE;

CREATE TABLE NYSE (`exchange` STRING, stock_symbol STRING, stock_date DATE, stock_price_open FLOAT, stock_price_high FLOAT, stock_price_low FLOAT, stock_price_close FLOAT, stock_volume INT, stock_price_avg_close FLOAT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Exchange](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords) is a Reserved keyword in HIVE

You can escape it using a backtick(``) symbol

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE NYSE(
`exchange` STRING
,stock_symbol STRING
,stock_date DATE
,stock_price_open FLOAT
,stock_price_high FLOAT
,stock_price_low FLOAT
,stock_price_close FLOAT
,stock_volume INT
,stock_price_avg_close FLOAT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

exchange is a keyword in hive so you cannot use. instead of use exchangee or anything else.
try this..

> create table nyse (exchangee String,stock_symbol String,stock_date
>   String,stock_price_open double,stock_price_high double,stock_price_low
>   double,stock_price_close double,stock_volume
>   double,stock_price_adj_close double) row format delimited fields
>   terminated by ",";